I am trying to create a pipeline in ADF and my CSV file opened in Notepad looks like this ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
SO, I have a file that is in the storage container as CSV. When I open the file in notepad, it looks like this.
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD and so on,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.
I would like to load this data from CSV file to Azure SQL table, but while running the pipeline, it gives me the error "The name of Column Index 17 is empty"
What settings need to be updated to load this?
enter image description here
I tried working with basic settings, but it not working at all.

Have you checked if there is a blank column header on position 17? meaning, on the first row, tow commas with no column name between them.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


This is my source data
Table2Id,Marks,name,designation,,col7
1,94,Michael Scofield,Structural Engineer,ok,ok2
3,100,Luffy,Pirate King,ok,ok2
5,98,Zoro,Swordsman,ok,ok2
6,26,Starc,Left-hand bowler,ok,ok2
7,24,chopper,Monster,ok,ok2
8,30,Ace,Fire-fist,ok,ok2

The above error occurs when the column name in the header is blank. You can see my 5th column name is blank and it was the reason for this error.
To resolve it, go to the given column and give any name or use dataflow for copying to target table.
Give your source and sink datasets in the dataflow and you can change the empty column name to required column name (Target will contain this column name) in the select transformation.

